# CSS3 animations make seemingly unrelated elements disappear in Mac/Webkit

Tags: css, animation, webkit

I have a page that uses a number of simple animations, including some JavaScript animations that add/remove CSS classes to elements with CSS3 animations for rotations.  I am not using canvas.

On the PC, the page looks great in Chrome/Safari, Firefox, and IE, but on Macs, a number of elements are completely missing on the page when it is viewed in WebKit (Chrome, and Safari 5.0.3).  It looks fine in Firefox on Mac.  The missing elements don't have any animations applied to them -- I don't see any connection between them and the animations.

The page validates, the CSS nearly validates except for the vendor extensions and the zoom property in my clearfix.  Disabling all of the JavaScript on the page doesn't change anything.  The missing elements are in the source, they are just not visible on the page.

At first glance, it looks like the Z-indexes have gotten screwy on the invisible elements.  Changing these doesn't affect the problem though.  Removing all of the absolute, relative, fixed positions, as well as floated elements in the entire document doesn't affect the problem.  The only action that does anything, is removing all of the Webkit animations.
And when I apply all of the animations, nearly everything on the page disappears!

Here is an example of one of my animations -- simple stuff:

```
@-webkit-keyframes propeller {
    0% {-webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);}
    50% {-webkit-transform: rotateX(1deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);}
}

#element {
    -webkit-animation:propeller 1s linear;
    -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%;
}
```

Even if the animation is not called, simply the presence of the keyframes causes the page to break.
If I use this animation in particular (just the -webkit- vendor prefix), it causes a large form to vanish that is a sibling of the great-great ancestor of "#element."

Here is a link to the page I'm working on.  I had nothing to do with the design: 
http://goo.gl/6XXcV

All of the animations are contained in animations.css and all the JavaScript animations are in general.js.

This has been very slow-going for me since I don't have a Mac -- I'm just using Microsoft Expression Web 4 SuperPreview -- but my client has a Mac and is not impressed.  Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I just pulled up the site in Chrome for mac and Firefox for mac (versions 22.0.1229.94 and 14.0.1 respectively) and aside from a couple spacing differences (which are minor) the look the same.  The only odd thing I see is the light blue background showing up next to all the graphics if your window is narrow enough to warrant (the seemingly needless) horizontal scroll.

What exactly is missing?

Comment: Thanks very much for your help and for mentioning the other bugs.  If I check the page in Expression Web's Safari (Mac) 5.0.3 service, nearly all of the elements (and I mean everything - all the blog posts, the menus, the forms, and all the text) are missing on the page except for the large background images on the top and bottom of the page.  If I start commenting-out the Webkit animations, the elements start reappearing in no logical order, until all of the Webkit animations are removed and the whole page renders as it should.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, the trouble turned out to be from bugs in Microsoft Expression Web 4 SuperPreview with their Mac/Safari 5.0.3 emulator service.  When any -webkit- vendor prefixes are used for CSS3 animations, it causes elements seemingly unrelated to the animations to behave as if they have visibility:hidden.

The similar problems with the disappearing elements first reported by my client using an actual Mac with Chrome seem to be from a bad .svg font conversion that was being used with @font-face.  Although the svg font was rendering on Mac/Webkit, it appeared to be destroying styles on elements in which it was used as well as parent elements.  When I converted the font once more to svg using a different conversion utility, the problem resolved.  Weird.